# Convert a Comma Seperate Value to JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to Convert a Comma Separated value of array to JSON object to formats below mentioned

INPUT

swedish,chinese,english,hindi

OUTPUT

```
Object {swedish: swedish, chinese: chinese, english: english,hindi: hindi}
```

Comment: `obj.data.split(',').map(function(item){ var obj={};obj[item]=item; return obj; })`

Comment: Here's a more "old school" version: https://jsfiddle.net/su12o2rp/ @RayonDabre you should add that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
var temp = {"data":"swedish,chinese"}
temp.data= temp.data.split(',').reduce((res,x)=>{
  res[x] = x;
  return res
},{});
console.log(temp);
```

will give

```
{"data":{"swedish":"swedish","chinese":"chinese"}}
```

Comment: It Worked @jagsSparrow

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array#map` over `commaSeperated.split(',')` returned array and return `object` with same `key-value` from the `callback` and wrap the `array` returned by `.map` in `object` having key as `data`

```js
var obj = {
  "data": "swedish,chinese"
};
var op = obj.data.split(',').map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[item] = item;
  return obj;
});
console.log({
  data: op
});
```

**Edit:** If expecting `object` as a response,

```js
var obj = {
  "data": "swedish,chinese"
};
var op = {
  data: {}
};
obj.data.split(',').forEach(function(item) {
  op.data[item] = item;
});
console.log(op);
```

Comment: output data is `object`  not array.

Comment: @JagsSparrow, That would not do much difference... I have updated it in the post anyway...

Comment: again `op` variable is array instead it should be `object` 

`{"swedish":"swedish","chinese":"chinese"}` vs `[
    {
      "swedish": "swedish"
    },
    {
      "chinese": "chinese"
    }
  ]`
a lot difference

Comment: @JagsSparrow, Have updated it! I did not read the question well! But I would use `array` instead of `object` for the sake of _simplicity_

Comment: ;) it suffice the answer now +1

Comment: Helpfull one..!! Thanks